# python pandas logical operators on blocks of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset loaded into a pandas DataFrame, like following:

```
n=2
np.random.seed(1)
dt = pd.DataFrame((np.random.rand(5, 2*n+1)*1000).round(), columns=['id', 'x_0', 'y_0', 'x_1', 'y_1'])
>>> dt
    id  x_0  y_0  x_1  y_1
0  417  720    0  302  147
1   92  186  346  397  539
2  419  685  204  878   27
3  670  417  559  140  198
4  801  968  313  692  876

[5 rows x 5 columns]
```

I am aware this works only for n=2, however at this point I don't know how to construct column names for any n (but I guess this is a question for another topic).

In general I can have n blocks of x and y columns (which are monthly data).

What I need is to check if values of both x_i and y_i exceed a certain amount in the same month, and if it does in any of the n months return a 1, else 0.

So, I am fiddling with:

```
>>> (dt[range(1, 2*n+1, 2)] > 400)
     x_0    x_1
0   True  False
1  False  False
2   True   True
3   True  False
4   True   True

[5 rows x 2 columns]
>>> (dt[range(2, 2*n+1, 2)] > 300)
     y_0    y_1
0  False  False
1   True   True
2  False  False
3   True  False
4   True   True

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

where I want to check if `x_i` values exceed `400` and `y_i` exceed `300`. This yields two DataFrames of x and y values (`n` columns wide), which is OK. But when I try:

```
(dt[range(1, 2*n+1, 2)] > 400) & (dt[range(2, 2*n+1, 2)] > 300)
```

it does not apply & operator by elements, but returns a 2*n DataFrame of NaNs:

```
   x_0  x_1  y_0  y_1
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I am clearly missing something here. The question is what is the logic behind and how to get this working.

If I got this working I would try to make us of the `any()` function with `apply()`.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

*Edit
Here is also an R snippet that solves the problem. Maybe the R approach to my Python code is "burdening" me here.

```
> n=2
> dt <- data.frame(id = c(417, 92, 419, 670, 801),
+                     x_0 = c(720, 186, 685, 417, 968),
+                     y_0 = c(0, 346, 204, 559, 313),
+                     x_1 = c(302, 397, 878, 140, 692),
+                     y_1 = c(147, 539, 27, 198, 876))

> (x <- (dt[,seq(2, 2*n+1, by=2)] > 400) & (dt[,seq(3, 2*n+1, by=2)] > 300))
       x_0   x_1
[1,] FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE FALSE
[5,]  TRUE  TRUE
> (result <- apply(x, 1, any, na.rm=T))
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: hint: in the attempt of using `&`, what did you expect the column names in the result to be?

Comment: I expected a DataFrame with n columns, where & is applied to each element of x_i and y_i, e.g. I expected the first result column to be [F, F, F, T, T] and second [F, F, F, F, T].

Answer (score 0):

this uses indexing by column name, and doesn't use logical operators on columns, rather than that it traverses rows with apply function:

```
n=2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dt = pd.DataFrame((np.random.rand(5, 2*n+1)*1000).round(), columns=['id', 'x_0', 'y_0', 'x_1', 'y_1'])
print dt

def check_x(x):
    value=0
    columns_with_x = [col for col in x.index if 'x_' in col]
    columns_with_y = [col for col in x.index if 'y_' in col]
    for each_col_x in columns_with_x:
        if x[each_col_x] > 400:
            for each_col_y in columns_with_y:
                if x[each_col_y] > 300:
                    value=1
    return value

checked = dt.apply(check_x, axis=1)

print checked
```

output:

```
    id  x_0  y_0  x_1  y_1
0  251  525  976  743  206
1  324  354  238  413   93
2   21  999  731  416  431
3  652  926  131  510  627
4  124  387  747  972  678

0    1
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hi yemu, thanks for the answer. I checked it and it is not exactly what I need, I guess I didn't phrase the question right. For loop should take two by two columns (`for i = 0 to n-1`), i.e. `x_0` and `y_0` and check `(x_0>400) & (y_0>400)`, but that is similar to what I tried, only I wanted to use the data frame.